# My textarea does not stretch 100% height

Tags: html, css, resize, textarea

Ok so I am using Jquery-ui resizable, so the user can control it.
The problem I am having is on the bottom half there is a textarea that is not expanding to 100% height.
Eventually, the textarea will be controlled by the codemirror library.
In my fiddle I have not included anything with code mirror, to keep it simple.
I think the form tag has something to do with it, since it is a block element.

```
<form>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id='ilo'>
            <div id='iloWrapper'></div>
            <div id='handle' class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="editor">
            <div class="edit-tool-bar"></div>
            <div class="editor-window">
                <textarea id="tArea"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mooch201/PBs6W/1/)

[UPDATE]
Here is a new fiddle based on the answer from audre7.
As you can see The textarea is 100% but it is expanding well past the bottom of the page.
All I want is 2 sections one top and one bottom.
The bottom section will have 2 items in it the top item will not scroll but be sticky to the top of that bottom section.
The textarea will take up the rest of the room in the bottom section, and it will be able to scroll vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the container of the textarea in a position absolute, and it seems to work as you want.

```
.editor-window{
 position:absolute;   
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what I want. But there is one issue with that the scroll bar's bottom arrow( the one pointing down ) is cut off. It looks like the cut off is due to the div with "edit-tool-bar" pushing it down.

Comment: Just an FYI you can remove/ change any of the existing CSS I have in there, since most of it was my playing around with it to get this to work.

Comment: I don't really understand the issue... But if its a matter of width, you can use `box-sizing: border-box` [your fiddle with modification](http://jsfiddle.net/audre7/PBs6W/5/)

Comment: I added an update for you explaining a little better on what i am looking for. thanks

Comment: [Ok, here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/audre7/37AVW/1/). I hope i understand this time :) So, since the first content block is `height:50%` and your main wrapper is in `absolute` and has a `top:30px`, **the room remains is : 50% - 30px**. There's a css3 property `.editor-window{height : calc:-webkit-calc(50% - 30px);}`. That's the only way i see, without using javascript, or a fixed position.